# Random Gaussian issues

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to generate a random.gauss numbers but I have  message error. Here is my code:

```
import sys,os
import numpy as np
from random import gauss


previous_value1=1018.163072765074389
previous_value2=0.004264112033664


alea_var_n=random.gauss(1,2)
alea_var_tau=random.gauss(1,2)


new_var_n= previous_value1*(1.0+alea_var_n)
new_var_tau=previous_value2*(1.0+alea_var_tau)

print 'new_var_n',new_var_n
print 'new_var_tau',new_var_tau
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lolo.py", line 15, in <module>
    alea_var_n=random.gauss(1,2)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'gauss'
```

Someone know what's wrong, I'm a newbye with python. Or is it a numpy version problem.

Comment: I changed your tag to `Python`. Python 3.x won't allow those print statements, and your error suggests that you are not getting any syntax errors (which would be raised before the error you mention).

Answer (score 4):

For a faster option, see Benjamin Bannier's solution (which I gave a +1 to). Your present code that you posted will not work for the following reason: your import statement

```
from random import gauss
```

adds `gauss` to your namespace but not `random`. You need to do this instead:

```
alea_var_n = gauss(1, 2)
```

The error in your post, however, is not the error you should get when you run the code that you have posted above. Instead, you will get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

Are you sure you have posted the code that generated that error? Or have you somehow included the wrong error in your post?

Answer (score 3):

Justin Barber shows you an immediate solution for your problem.

Since you are using NumPy you could however use their generators as well since they appear to be significantly faster (about a factor 5-7 on my machine), e.g.

```
alea_var_n = np.random.normal(1, 2)
```